# Redeclare model with "outer" parameters

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I tried redeclare model that contain global (outer) parameter. Here simple example of my code:

```
package tests

model M0
  inner parameter Real a = 1;
end M0;
 
model M1
  extends tests.M0;
  replaceable tests.M3 c;
end M1;

model M2
  outer constant Real a;
end M2;

model M3
  extends tests.M2;
  Real b;
equation
  b = a;
end M3;

model M4
  extends tests.M2;
  Real b2;
  equation
  b2 = a;
end M4;


model test1
  tests.M1 X;
end test1;

model test2
  tests.M1 X(redeclare each tests.M4 c);
end test2;


end tests;
```

Test1 works fine, but with test2 I have warning `An inner declaration for outer component a could not be found and was automatically generated.`
Without "inner/outer" all works fine.
The warning occurs even if M3 and model M4 have identically code

```
model M3 // and M4
  outer constant Real a;
  Real b;
  equation
  b = a;
end M3;
```

or if redeclare the same model

```
model test3
  tests.M1 X(redeclare tests.M3 c);
end test3;
```

I am using OM 1.18

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that `b` is defined in `M3` but not in `M4`. Modifying `M4` to

```
model M4
  extends tests.M2;
  Real b, b2;
equation 
  b = a;
  b2 = a;
end M4;
```

or

```
model M4
  extends tests.M2;
  Real b;
equation 
  b = a;
end M4;
```

removes the respective warnings in Dymola.

This comes down to [plug-compatibility](https://mbe.modelica.university/components/architectures/int_vs_imp/#plug-compatibility), which in this example means, that every public variable in `M3` must be present in `M4` as well.

As plug-compatibility only refers to public variables, defining b to be protected in `M3` should also resolve the issue:

```
model M3
  extends tests.M2;
protected 
  Real b;
equation 
  b = a;
end M3;
```

Note: I didn't test it with OpenModelica...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the warning occurs even if M3 and model M4 have identically code. I corrected my question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works in Dymola, even though there is one issue:

In `M0` you declared `a` as a `parameter`

```
inner parameter Real a = 1;
```

But in `M2` you are looking for a constant

```
outer constant Real a;
```

Both tools don't care much about that fact, which seems strange.

In OpenModelica I guess you have hit a bug. You are using inner/outer in an uncommon way. Changing your setup to a more common style with the inner variable defined in a top-level-component (now named `World`) works:

```
package tests

model World
  inner parameter Real a = 1;
end World;

model M1
  replaceable tests.M3 c;
end M1;

model M2
  outer World w;
  parameter Real a = w.a;
end M2;

model M3
  extends tests.M2;
  Real b;
equation 
  b = a;
end M3;

model M4
  extends tests.M2;
  Real b2;
equation 
  b2 = a;
end M4;

model test1
  inner World w;
  tests.M1 X;
end test1;

model test2
  inner World w;
  tests.M1 X(redeclare each tests.M4 c);
end test2;

end tests;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have big model that worked fine 2 or 3 years ago (in OpenModelica). Model include replaceable models with inner parameters. I agree that it is not very good style, I shouldn't have used this method. But I don't want to rewrite it.

Comment: Since it worked before and it works in Dymola, I would create a bug report at https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues

Comment: Your usage of inner/outer is indeed more common. But the code of @Tyomich is still possible since test2.X.a (inner) is hierarchically higher then test2.X.c.a (outer) and they are, thus, the same variable. Cf. example in Modelica Language Specification 3.5, Section 5.4.